# Overlap scripted P

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, amsmath

I would like to overlap the scripted P (i.e. `\mathscr{P}`) such that it produces something similar to the picture below. (Preferably, the distance between the two P's should not be much; they should be separate enough so that the overlap does not look like a bold P, but close enough so that the letter does not take up much more space than `\mathscr{P}`.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: `$\put(1,-1){\ensuremath{\mathscr{P}}}\mathscr{P}$`? But that looks dreadful with the `\mathscr` from `mathrsfs` anyway; what font/package are you using for `\mathscr`?

Comment: @frabjous this is similar to what I am looking for, but I think one of the letters needs to be "included in" the other more, similar to the ```\mathbb``` font

Comment: I"m not entirely sure I understand what you want, but wouldn't that require the two P's to be a completely different shape from each other? That's not a (La)TeX question then, it's a font design question.

Comment: @frabjous Would it be difficult to design such a font?

Comment: I've never designed a font, so don't ask me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use pdflatex, you may be able to just use an outline of an existing letter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{white}
\def\thickness{.1}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{P}$ \outline{$\mathscr{P}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the `\def` of `\thickness`, for example, from .1 to .3 can be used to change the appearance of the result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I should have clarified that by "not bold" I meant for the resultant font to be such that after overlapping the letters the result is not bold-looking (rather than white).

Comment: @JacksonBodoviwitz I should have mentioned that changing the definition of `\thickness` will change the appearance of the result with this approach